# Publisher concatenation if one of them is empty

Tags: kotlin, reactor

I am trying to concatenate two publishers, but I know that `this` can be empty and I want result be empty too.

```
fun Flux<String>.prefixWith(rhs: Mono<String>) = rhs
    .flux()
    .concatWith(this)
```

That just returns `rhs` as expected. How to return empty `Flux` if `this` is empty?

Comment: I can use ```switchMap``` for that and get distinct result, and It can be a solution in my case, but that just doesn't seem right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hasElements()` method ([doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#hasElements--)) of `Flux` to find out if the flux has elements or not, and then using `flatMapMany`, return the concatenation if elements are present, or the empty flux itself if no elements are present.

```
fun Flux<String>.prefixWith(rhs: Mono<String>) = this.hasElements().flatMapMany<String> {
    if (it) {
        rhs.concatWith(this) //when the flux has elements
    } else {
        this //this would be empty flux
    }
}
```